# Magento 2: How to move additional product attributes to Details tab?

Tags: magento2, product, template, design, tabs

In Blank theme, attributes other than description display under **More information** tab.
In my theme, I want to move attributes from **More Information** to **Details** tab.

> Example:
>   **Details** tab contains description. **More information** tab contains color and brand.

How to move **only** color attribute from **More information** to **Details** tab?

How to move **both** color and brand attributes and remove **More information** tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all u need to create ur theme http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

In your theme u have to override Magento Default files.

**magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 SW-THEMES. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/jquery.zoom.min.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Catalog‌​\templates\product\v‌​iew\attribute.phtml** as per your requirement.

```
   /**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}

$colorValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

?>
<?php if ($colorValue): ?>
    <div><?php echo $colorValue; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
    <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Display as per your design requirement.

Let me know if any issue.

Thanks

Comment: This works for copying the value of attribute. However I would like to display the label too. "Color: Red" instead of "Red" only. The file attributes.phtml displays those attributes and labels in the "More information" tab. How to copy the same format to "Description" tab? Thanks

Comment: For Label `$colorLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontendLabel();`

Comment: Thanks. Could you help to answer my new question about overriding a file? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153591/how-to-override-file-vendor-magento-module-catalog-block-product-view-attributes